# fix a div/button/link to a background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am having an annoying issue to position an element on top of a background image. Say we have a html as :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="background:url('image.png'); background-size:cover;">
        <button>Button </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The button should be placed at `left: 50px; top: 100px;` against the original image, but because the device screen ( desktop chrome or ios safari ) change, and the `background-size: cover;` property, the image is actually scaled, so the button would not appear at the right position.
I tried another way :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style = "margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:100%;">
        <img src="image.png" width="100%" />
        <button style="top: -100;z-index: 5;">Button </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way the page may scroll because the image might beyond screen height, once i positioned the button to the right place, and changed to another device resolution, the position was altered again.

I also tried javascript to listen to resize event to absolutely position the button, it still has obvious difference between desktop and ios screens.

How can i make it ? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
If the image is scaled due to screen resolution, i want the button be scaled same ratio too. It would be great to find a way without complex javascript.

Comment: What are the dimensions of your image?

Comment: The dimensions might be : 640*1008 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button size change with the scale of the page, so you must add width and height style for that in% unit. Because pixel  is a fix unit on  different devices but % depends on device resolution. And finally you can add min-width and min-height or max-width and max-height to your div style to have a good control on other devices. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS `position absolute` to your **image** and **button** elements. In this way you will be able to set their position accordingly to their parent element `<div>`.

http://jsbin.com/mevuxizuzu/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;">
        <img style="position:absolute" src="image.png" width="100%" />
        <button style="position:absolute; left: 50px; top: 100px;z-index: 5;">Button </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. However, if you change the browser resolution, for example from 1920*1080 to 640*1136, you can notice the button position on the image is changed. I want it be fixed to the image, for example it is initially on the bat, no matter the image scale, it still is on the bat and its size scale as well. Sorry if i didnot express clearly about the **against the image**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the position:absolute; for your button and set the right place with top and left position with %, because your width and height are based on % not pixels .

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;">
        <img style="position:absolute" src="image.png" width="100%" />
        <button style="position:absolute; left: 15%; top: 10%;z-index: 5;">Button </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code that use relative position for the button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    button {
      position: relative;
      left: 20px;
      top:100px;
    }
    .bd{
      background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/650/1000/sports/1/');
      background-size: cover;
      height: 1000px;
      width: 650px;

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bd" style="width:100%;">
        <img style="position:absolute" src="" width="100%" />

        <button>Button </button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/pemafigafa/3/

Comment: I made some changes basing on this and @navid-nazarian 's advice : http://jsbin.com/favolipimu/2/ . That is close, but not ideal yet. I suspect that it cannot be done witiout some JS.